# How to display all " g++ -Wall " error warnings in SysntasticCheck for vim?

Tags: c++, vim, gcc-warning

I want to display all the warning messages that g++ -Wall command displays for the cpp files in syntasticcheck for vim.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the gcc plugin you can set the options passed to the C compiler with

```
let g:syntastic_c_compiler_options = '-Wall'
```

and similarly for C++ files

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = '-Wall'
```

Alternatively if you build with `cmake` you could also generate a compilation database with

```
% cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=YES /path/to/sources
```

and then use the syntastic clang-check plugin which for checking uses exactly the flags used to compile the file.

Comment: @nightfury: I made a small correction since I only gave the option for C files (not C++) before.